# How can transfer a file between two iOS apps directly?

Tags: ios, url, argument-passing, file-storage

I want to transfer a 3D data file from one app to another. The first app generates the 3D file using a camera, and the second stores it and allows preview. After googling around and searching SO for a while, I still couldn't find an answer. Most solutions use URLs to pass data between apps, but I need to pass a file. How can I transfer files directly instead of using a URL? Or can I use URLs to get a file from another app's storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the **app groups** capability of iOS.

In the *capabilities* section of your Xcode project you can enable an app group, such as *group.com.yourname.yourapp*.  You will need to enable the same application group for both of your apps and ensure that are both signed by the same Team ID

You can then [access the shared application group directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW83) using

```
NSURL *groupURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
    containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:
       @"group.com.yourname.yourapp"];
```

Comment: thanks! Do you mean that I use my first app to store the file in the group,then shut down it and run the second app to read the file from the group?  But can I notify the second app directly as soon as I generate the file in the first app?

Comment: To notify you would need to use a URL to launch the second app